# Symfony 2 Forms - add new item to Collection server-side, depending on button clicked

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form which contains a Collection of an unspecified number of subforms.  I want to have functionality allowing the user to add a new, blank item to the Collection for them to fill in.  The Symfony docs tell us how to do this using Javascript clientside to add new blank form controls, which are then submitted and persisted as normal, but I'd like to do it serverside in the controller, without Javascript.

The problem I'm encountering is to do with the way Symfony Forms work.  I have an "Add" button added to my main form, and I intend to detect whether it is that button which has been clicked, so that I can add the blank item to the Collection and re-render the form.  But to detect the click I need to call $this->createForm and at that point the form is fixed with the original set of items, it's too late to add an extra one.

```
//Symfony Action

//A Person has many Selections
$person = $this->getPerson($id)

//All fields are frozen at this point, according to data in $person!
$form = $this->createForm(new SelectionsType($lookups), $person);
$form->handleRequest($request);

//Ideally I'd somehow do this test earlier, but I need $form to do it...
if ($form->get('add')->isClicked() )
{
    //TOO LATE!
    $person->getSelections()->add(new Selection() );
}

if ($form->isValid())
{
    if ($form->get('save')->isClicked() )
    {
        //Persist
    }
}

//Render page etc
```

Things I've thought about:

- Putting the Add button in a completely different form on the same page, which submits to a different Action which can then do some preparatory work before forwarding to the main Action above
- Inspecting submitted HTTP data directly to note that Add has been clicked (shame not to use the standard Symfony method)
- Give up and use Javascript as suggested (it might work in this example, but I'd like to have the option of carrying out server-side activity (without AJAX...) as part of adding the new blank item)

How can I best achieve this in a proper Symfony way?

EDIT Just seen this: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5231, which is essentially a feature request to allow what I'm after.  One suggestion a commenter makes is to add a blank item to the Collection and then remove it if it's not needed - I don't know how one would do that, but it sounds promising.

ANOTHER EDIT It occurs to me that, because I need two different aspects of the $form I'm creating, I could maybe just make the $form, use it to handle the request, detect the button click, and then throw that $form away, before altering my model and creating another $form.  I don't know if that would somehow fall foul of some rules about handling the submission twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end was have my Add button hit a separate Action, which then delegates to the main action with a flag to say "add a new Selection", as below:

```
public function selectionsAddAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    return $this->selectionsAction($request, $id, true);
}

public function selectionsAction(Request $request, $id, $addNew = false)
{
    $person = $this->getPerson($id);

    //Also use "add mode" if we just deleted the last one!
    if (!$person->getSelections()->count())
    {
            $addNew = true;
    }

    //$addNew is set by a separate action, hit by a different form with the Add button in
    if ($addNew)
    {
        $person->getSelections()->add(new Selection() );
    }

    //We now have the right number of items, and can build the form!
    $form = $this->createForm(new SelectionsType($lookups), $person);

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% but I think you could do the following...

```
//Symfony Action with (Request $request, ...)

//A Person has many Selections
$person = $this->getPerson($id)

//All fields are frozen at this point, according to data in $person!
$form = $this->createForm(new SelectionsType($lookups), $person);

if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $form->submit($request);

    if ($form->get('add')->isClicked()) {
        // Add thing
    } elseif ($form->isValid()) {
    // or 
    // } elseif ($form->get('save')->isClicked() && $form->isValid()) {
        // Persist and what not
    }
}

//Render page etc
```

I haven't tested it so I don't know whether it will trigger the form errors (or if it will actually work) so if it does (or it doesn't) I apologise.

Comment: Thanks @Qoop - that looks a bit like a paraphrase of my example, albeit not using _handleRequest_ and doing an explicit _submit_, am I missing a crucial difference?  For me, the key thing I lack is to actually do the "//Add thing" bit! If I add to my model then the form doesn't get the changes, and I don't know how to add to the form myself (so far I let the _createForm_ call do this for me)

Comment: I'll add the explanation in the answer.

Comment: Sorry I'm an idiot and my answer is pretty much just your question. The handleRequest & isMethod/submit change is for personal preference really. Are you sure the extra selection isn't being added and that the form is then just validating and then persisting meaning you're not being show the form? Also you would need to set the `Person` in the added `Selection` or the `Selection` will not be attached to any particular `Person`.

Comment: Ha, no problem! Yeah, I confirmed for certain that I wasn't getting an extra Selection in the form object.  You're right about needing to Person/Selection relationship, hadn't got that far!  I've actually managed to sort this out using my first bulleted suggestion (put Add in a different form, which runs the main action with a parameter set so it can know to add the blank item), so that's good.